# Shading in a simple closed curve

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I started thiking about this today and I have an answer I feel I can justify intuitively but not rigorously.

Let $\mathbb{S} = \{(x,y) \ | \ f(x,y)=c\}$ define the points on a simple closed curve (at least I think this is the right terminology; examples would be a circle, elipse or [heart curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20%28x%5E2%2by%5E2-1%29%5E3-x%5E2y%5E3=0)).

Is it always the case that set of points contained within the curve (i.e. the points that "shade it in") are equal to $\mathbb{S^*}=\{(x,y) \ | \ f(x,y) \lt c\}$

This seems to be true "intuitively" since you are making the $x, y$ values smaller and so $f(x,y)$ shrinks as well.  Can we perform some type of derivative on the curve to prove this?

Also, any help with terminology/notation would be greatly appreciated.  I think this falls under Topology but I'm not sure.

Comment: I notice both of the answers below give functions $f$ that are not defined everywhere inside the circle. If you insist that $f$ be a function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ you can just modify the ones below to $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$. The set $\{(x,y) : f(x,y) = 1\}$ is still the unit circle, but the region $\{(x,y) : f(x,y) < 1\}$ describes the **outside** of the circle.

Comment: This really is a perfect counter example the more I think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the case if we just play around with the usual parametrisation of the circle as $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|=c\}$. If we instead define a curve to be $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|^{-1}=c\}$$ then this defines a circle of radius $c^{-1}$ and the region $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|^{-1}<c\}$ is equal to $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|>c^{-1}\}$ which is the region we would normally call the *exterior* of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Note that taking $g(x,y) = 2 - f(x,y)$, we have $g$ equal to $1$ in exactly the same places as $f$, but the region where $f$ is less than one is precisely the region where $g$ is *greater* than one (and vice versa).

Also, discontinuous functions are perfectly legitimate functions! So actually if I tell you where $f$ takes the value $1$, I don't really tell you anything else about $f$. It's quite reasonable to have a function $f$ that is $1$ on the unit circle, then $7/8$ on a square around that, and everywhere else it's $\pi^{\pi^{7000}}$.

Answer (score 2):

With a few additional assumptions your statement becomes true.

Suppose $f$ is continuous. You've assumed that $S$ is a simple closed curve, so by the Jordan curve theorem, the complement of $S$ in the plane consists of two components, one unbounded and one bounded. The bounded component is what you are calling the points inside the curve. Let's write $B$ for the bounded component and $U$ for the unbounded component.

Suppose that at least one point $(x,y)$ in $B$ satisfies $f(x,y)<c$. Then all points in $B$ satisfy this inequality, since $B$ is connected (definition of component), and $S$ by assumption contains *all* points with $f(x,y)=c$. And if one point in $U$ satisfies $f(x,y)>c$, then all points in $U$ do too (same reasoning).

So if (1) $f$ is continuous, and (2) one point in the bounded component satifies $f(x,y)<c$, and (3) one point in the unbounded component satifies $f(x,y)>c$, then your statement is true.

If any one of these assumptions is dropped, the statement no longer holds. Here's an example where (1) and (2) hold but not (3). Let $f(P)$ be the distance from $P$ to the origin if that distance is $\leq 1$. If the distance to the origin is $>1$, say $r$, then let $f(P)=1/r$. Then $S=\{P:f(P)=1\}$ is the unit circle, but the locus of $f(P)<1$ is everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Really helpful.